# Generate multiple hash values from one stream with Crypto in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am working on a Node.js application. Readable stream from a child process' output is being piped into a writable stream from a Crypto module to generate 4 hash values (md5, sha1, sha256 and sha512). This module only allows to generate one hash at a time. After hashes are created, both this stream and hash values should be somehow passed further in order to be recorded to a file. I am currently stuck at creating the first hash value. How can I solve this problem? Part of the code can be seen below.

```js
import Crypto from 'crypto';
let md5 = Crypto.createHash('md5');
//How to generate another hash using the same input
md5.on('readable', () => {
    const data = md5.read();
    if (data) {
        console.log(md5.read());
    }
})
...
childProc.stdout.pipe(md5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple hashes from a single stream by piping to multiple transform streams.

```
import Crypto from 'crypto';
let md5 = Crypto.createHash('md5');
let sha1 = Crypto.createHash('sha1');

md5.on('readable', () => {
    const data = md5.read();
    if (data) console.log(data.toString('hex'));
})
sha1.on('readable', () => {
    const data = sha1.read();
    if (data) console.log(data.toString('hex'));
})

childProc.stdin.pipe(md5)
childProc.stdin.pipe(sha1)
```

This code will print the hash for each algorithm to stdout.